# Hiding image for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm trying to hide a certain image for mobile devices on my website. I've tried a various of html and css code and i cannot get it to work. It might have something to do with my div class's and Id tags.

please can someone try and get it to work for me?

HTML:

```
<section id="left-sidebar">
 <div class="logo">
    <a href="#intro" class="link-scroll">
      <img src="assets/images/other_images/logo.png" alt="description of image">
      <img src="assets/images/other_images/nav.png" class="nav">
    </a>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #left-sidebar .logo .nav  {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [@Media screen](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp):

> **screen**  Used for computer screens, tablets, smart-phones etc.

Combine it with `pixel-ratio` to fit your needs. [Check more examples here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

For example (for Samsung Galaxy S3):

```
/* ----------- Galaxy S3 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
{
    // insert here your custom styles
    #left-sidebar .logo .nav  {
       display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? did you checked the examples in the link I provided? you must check your device width and height and emulate in the rule parameters....

Comment: I've tried it on my mobile device and when i re-size the browser in windows it doesn't do anything. It's nothing to do with the div class's and id's which i initially thought because when i remove the @media screen part it removes the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.youClassname{display:inline;}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
      .yourClassname{
            display:none !important;
   }
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .yourClassname  {
            display:none !important;
   }
 }

</style>
```

Comment: pls consider to add your explanation to the answer , that will help more peoples later

Answer (score 0):

instead using `display:none` try this

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #left-sidebar .logo .nav  {
        display:hidden !important;
    }
}
```

this code will work if isn't still not working please check device width and go on

Comment: Thanks, still isn't working :/ It's really confusing. It works fine without the @media but as soon as i add it it doesn't effect it at all. I've tried re-sizing the browser and viewing it on my mobile device.

Comment: @smither123 try now made some changes

Answer (score 0):

I run  your HTML and CSS on JSFiddle. I just change your CSS to:

```
  img {
            display:none;
        }
```

and got [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sq1vp3p2/)

not sure if its this what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me, which was odd

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
      #left-sidebar .logo .nav  {
            display:none;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.youClassname{display:inline;}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
      .yourClassname{
            display:none !important;
   }
 }

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .yourClassname  {
            display:none !important;
   }
 }

</style>
```